# Characterization of the family of simple groups PSL(2,q) by tensor multiplicity

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-combinatorics, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group and $(\chi_i)$ its irreducible characters. Then $\forall i,j,k, \exists!n_{i,j}^k \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 0}$ such that     $$\chi_i \chi_j = \sum_k n_{i,j}^k \chi_k.$$

Let the **tensor multiplicity** of $G$ be $m(G):= \max_{i,j,k} (n_{i,j}^k)$; for ex. $m(A_5) = 2$ and $m(A_6) = 3$.

*Theorem*: Let $q > 5$ be a prime-power, then $$m(\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        2 & \text{ if } q \text{ even,} \\
        3 & \text{ if } q \text{ odd.} 
    \end{array}
\right.$$
*proof*: see (for example) the generic computation of $(n_{i,j}^k)$ for $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$ in [my talk](https://youtu.be/WbV6yAfgP2I) at 30:00. $\square$

This post is about the converse of above theorem.

Let $G$ be a non-abelian finite simple group with $m(G) \le 3$.
**Question**: Is it true that $G \simeq \mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$ for some prime-power $q$?

It was checked by GAP for $|G|<10^7$ (see Appendix).

*Remark*: The classification below suggests that the family $(\mathrm{PSL}(2,q))$ is the only one, among the usual infinite families of (non-abelian) finite simple groups, where the tensor multiplicity is bounded above. This would provide an other interesting characterization of this family.

---

**Appendix**

We improved our way to check as suggested by Mikko Korhonen in comment. Let $G$ be a finite group, $d_+(G)$ be the maximum among the degrees of complex irreducible characters of $G$, and $\Sigma(G)$ their sum. They are exactly $27$ non-abelian finite simple groups $|G|<10^7$ not isomorphic to some $\mathrm{PSL(2,q)}$. The classification below lists them ordered according to $d_+^2(G)/\Sigma(G)$, which is less than or equal to $m(G)$.

*Computation*

Each element of the list reads as $d_+^2(G)/\Sigma(G)$, its numerical approximation, $G$ and $|G|$.

```
gap> classification(10000000);
[ [ 256/63, 4.06349, PSU(3,3), 6048 ], 
[ 1125/208, 5.40865, PSU(3,4), 62400 ], 
[ 13/2, 6.5, PSL(3,3), 5616 ], 
[ 18432/2107, 8.74798, PSU(3,7), 5663616 ], 
[ 175/18, 9.72222, A7, 2520 ],
[ 2048/203, 10.0887, PSL(3,4), 20160 ], 
[ 175/16, 10.9375, A8, 20160 ], 
[ 279/25, 11.16, PSL(3,5), 372000 ], 
[ 729/64, 11.3906, PSp(4,3), 25920 ], 
[ 3025/218, 13.8761, M11, 7920 ],
[ 8281/484, 17.1095, Sz(8), 29120 ], 
[ 10368/553, 18.7486, PSU(3,5), 126000 ], 
[ 7225/271, 26.6605, PSp(4,4), 979200 ], 
[ 321489/11210, 28.6788, PSU(3,8), 5515776 ],
[ 43681/1464, 29.8367, J_1, 175560 ], 
[ 704/21, 33.5238, M12, 95040 ], 
[ 23328/683, 34.1552, A9, 181440 ], 
[ 5472/155, 35.3032, PSL(3,7), 1876896 ], 
[ 28224/709, 39.8082, J_2, 604800 ],
[ 16384/319, 51.3605, PSp(6,2), 1451520 ], 
[ 321489/5356, 60.0241, A10, 1814400 ], 
[ 152100/2519, 60.3811, PSp(4,5), 4680000 ], 
[ 21175/258, 82.0736, M22, 443520 ],
[ 173056/1875, 92.2965, G(2, 3), 4245696 ], 
[ 20800/207, 100.483, PSL(4,3), 6065280 ], 
[ 775/7, 110.714, PSL(5,2), 9999360 ], 
[ 28672/227, 126.308, PSU(4,3), 3265920 ] ]
```

Below is the alternative classification suggested by Goeff Robinson in comment, considering $d_+(G)/c(G)$, with $c(G)$ the class number of $G$:

```
gap> classification2(10000000);
[ [ 16/7, 2.28571, PSU(3,3), 6048 ], 
[ 13/4, 3.25, PSL(3,3), 5616 ], 
[ 75/22, 3.40909, PSU(3,4), 62400 ], 
[ 35/9, 3.88889, A7, 2520 ], 
[ 81/20, 4.05, PSp(4,3), 25920 ],
[ 5, 5., A8, 20160 ], 
[ 11/2, 5.5, M11, 7920 ], 
[ 31/5, 6.2, PSL(3,5), 372000 ], 
[ 32/5, 6.4, PSL(3,4), 20160 ], 
[ 192/29, 6.62069, PSU(3,7), 5663616 ], 
[ 91/11, 8.27273, Sz(8), 29120 ],
[ 72/7, 10.2857, PSU(3,5), 126000 ], 
[ 176/15, 11.7333, M12, 95040 ], 
[ 12, 12., A9, 181440 ], 
[ 340/27, 12.5926, PSp(4,4), 979200 ], 
[ 209/15, 13.9333, J_1, 175560 ],
[ 16, 16., J_2, 604800 ], 
[ 256/15, 17.0667, PSp(6,2), 1451520 ], 
[ 81/4, 20.25, PSU(3,8), 5515776 ], 
[ 228/11, 20.7273, PSL(3,7), 1876896 ], 
[ 390/17, 22.9412, PSp(4,5), 4680000 ],
[ 189/8, 23.625, A10, 1814400 ], 
[ 385/12, 32.0833, M22, 443520 ], 
[ 1040/29, 35.8621, PSL(4,3), 6065280 ], 
[ 832/23, 36.1739, G(2, 3), 4245696 ], 
[ 224/5, 44.8, PSU(4,3), 3265920 ],
[ 1240/27, 45.9259, PSL(5,2), 9999360 ] ]
```

*Code*

```
classification:=function(n)  #for Geoff way: classification2:=function(n)
    local it,LL,g,A,L,l,dmax,S,c,cc;
    it:=SimpleGroupsIterator(2520,n);; #2520=|A_7|
    LL:=[];;
    for g in it do
        A:=StructureDescription(g);;
        if Length(A)<6 or List([1..6],i->A[i])<>"PSL(2," then #PSL(2,q) excluded
            L:=CharacterDegrees(g);;
            l:=Length(L);;
            dmax:=L[l][1];;
            S:=Sum(L,i->i[1]*i[2]); #Goeff way: Sum(L,i->i[2]); 
                    cc:=dmax^2/S;;
            Add(LL,[cc,Float(cc),g,Order(g)]);;
        fi; 
    od;
    Sort(LL);
    return LL;
end;;
```

Recall that $A_7$ is the smallest non-abelian finite simple group not isomorphic to some $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$.

Comment: Let $\Sigma(G)$ be the sum of the degrees of complex irreducible characters of $G$. Here is another question. For $G$ finite simple and not isomorphic to $\operatorname{PSL}_2(q)$, does there exist an irreducible character $\chi$ such that $3 \Sigma(G) < \chi(1)^2$? Then in the tensor product $\chi \otimes \chi$ some irreducible occurs with multiplicity $> 3$. There are upper bounds for $\Sigma(G)$ in the literature, maybe for $G$ of Lie type taking $\chi$ to be the Steinberg character would suffice.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: The answer to your question is yes for $|G| \le 10^6$, where the smallest possible $\chi(1)^2/\Sigma(G)$ is $256/63 \simeq 4.06$ (given by $G = \mathrm{PSU}(3,3)$ only), so that $4 \Sigma(G) < \chi(1)^2$ is also true.

Comment: As an even cruder bound, it  is (more than) enough to find an irreducible character with $\chi(1) > 3k$, where the simple group $G$  has $k$ conjugacy classes. It is a conjecture (originally formulated in a more general form by D. Gluck, mainly motivated by solvable groups) that a simple group $G$ should have an irreducible character $\chi$ with $\chi(1) > |G|^{\frac{1}{3}}.$ There are probably only finitely many families of simple groups of Lie type with $k = k(G) > \frac{|G|^{1/3}}{3}$ ( which include ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$), and finitely many alternating groups satisfy that inequality.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: yes, in fact, let $G$ be a non-abelian finite simple group with $|G| \le 10^6$,  let $\chi$ be an irreducible character of maximal degree and let $k$ be the class number. Then $\chi(1) \le 3k$ if and only if $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{PSL(2,q)}$ for some $q$ or $\mathrm{PSU(3,3)}$, see the added list in the post. I guess it is also true without retriction on $|G|$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: the point is that PSL2 is the only (usual) infinite family of non-abelian finite simple groups on which $m(G)$ is bounded above. And it turns out that this above bound is $3$.

Answer (score 5):

The check of $\textrm{max}\{\textrm{deg}(\chi)\mid \chi \in \textrm{Irr}(G)\} > 3   k$ could be extended to more finite simple groups (including all sporadics) by using the character tables which are available in GAP:

```
simpnames:= AllCharacterTableNames( IsSimple, true, IsAbelian, false);
LL := [];;                      
for nam in simpnames do  
  Print(nam," ");        
  t := CharacterTable(nam);   
  d := Maximum(List(Irr(t),Degree));  
  k := NrConjugacyClasses(t);    
  Print([d,k,Float(d/k)],"\n");  
  Add(LL, [d/k,Float(d/k),nam, Size(t),d,k]);
od;                         
Sort(LL, {a,b} -> a[4] <= b[4]);   
Filtered(LL, a-> a[1] <= 3);
```

From the result I would guess the following statement:

*G is non-abelian simple with max. character degree $\leq 3k$ iff  G = PSU(3,3) or PSL(2,q).*

Sketch of proof:

- G sporadic: checked above (GAP, resp. ATLAS)
- G alternating: (note that $A_5\cong PSL(2,4)$ and $A_6 \cong PSL(2,9)$ are among the exceptions) Symmetric group $S_n$ has representation for partition
  (2,2,2, ...., 2,2 or 1)
  and the hook formula and Stirling approximation of $n!$ yield that
  its degree grows with $n$ like $e^n$, while the number of conjugacy classes
  of $S_n$ (= number of partitions of $n$) grows like $e^{const \sqrt{n}}$.

  (The numbers for the alternating group differ at most by a factor $2$).
- G of Lie type of rank l:

  - they always have the Steinberg representation of degree $q^{N}$ where $N$ is the number of postive roots of $G$,  which is roughly $N \sim l^2$
  - their number of conjugacy classes is bounded by $< c q^l$ for some constant c

  (so only rank $l=1$, $PSL_2(q)$, or very small $l$ and $q$ will give exceptions)

So, asymptotically the statement looks ok, one needs to be a bit more precise to get the list of small exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

Liebeck and Pyber [Journal of Algebra 198, 538-562, Th. 1] showed that a finite simple group of Lie type of (untwisted) rank $r$ over $\mathbf{F}_q$ has at most $(6q)^r$ conjugacy classes. On the other hand, the Steinberg character has degree $q^{(d-r)/2}$ (where $d$ is the dimension of the associated algebraic group), so as soon as $q>6$ and $d>3r$ (which holds except for $PSL_2$), we have a character with $\chi(1)>3k$, and Geoff Robinson's argument applies.

Comment: Indeed, I've added it (it's the dimension of the algebraic group).

Comment: Very good! So it remains to consider the twisted case, the alternating groups and the sporadic groups.

Comment: The result of Liebeck and Pyber does apply to the twisted groups of Lie type, and I think that the Steinberg character has the same degree also for twisted groups; in that case, the argument also applies to twisted groups.

Comment: Small detail: for $q < 6$, the same argument works if $d > 7r$. Then check separately the finite number of groups that occur for $q < 6$ and $d \leq 7r$.